# cmd- Copying file content into specific lines of an existing file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe

I'm trying to make an batch file that will copy the contents of a .cfg file into another .cfg file. The problem I'm having is that I want the contents of the first file to be placed at specific lines of the destination file, for example, placing the contents between line 300 and 343 and overwriting the original content within those lines.

Any way of doing this?

If there isn't a way to detect specific lines maybe there is a way to detect a specific string, like an ID?

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use 3rd party tools in your environment you can use a regex CLI tool to find and then replace the lines / values you need. The tool can be called using batch scripts.

Example Tools from another question:
https://superuser.com/questions/339118/regex-replace-from-command-line